# How to add a hyperlink to a shape that refers to a slide within a presentation that was created with excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am working in Excel VBA. I want to add to shape a hyperlink which refers to slide of a presentation that I have created in excel VBA. The name of the shape which is on slide 1 is "FName".

Also, myPresentation is declared as `Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add`

I hope you can help me. If anything is unclear I am happy to explain it in more detail.

```
Dim strHyperlink As String
Dim sldX As Slide

Set sldX = myPresentation.Slides(slideNumber)



strHyperlink = sldX.SlideID & "," & sldX.SlideIndex & "," & myPresentation.Slides(slideNumber).Shapes("Title 1").TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text
'strHyperlink = slideNumber & ". " & myPresentation.Slides(slideNumber).Name

myPresentation.Windows(1).Activate

With myPresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(FName).TextFrame.TextRange.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
    
            .Action = ppActionHyperlink
            .Hyperlink.Address = ""
            .Hyperlink.SubAdress = strHyperlink
    
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: So what is not working with your code? If your shape name is `FName` then you should most probably pass the name as a string e.g  `.Shapes("FName")`

Comment: For some reason the code skips the part ```.Hyperlink.SubAdress = strHyperlink``` and doesn't execute it. Can you tell me why?

Comment: and ```FName``` is variable declared as a String

Comment: For one - You have a typo there, `SubAdress`.... try correcting it and try again? @Vincent

Comment: Suggestion:  ALWAYS put Option Explicit at the top of each module. That forces you to define all variables, and will point out any typos you've made in variable names.